# How to run Swing.timer concurrently without lag or slow performance

Tags: java, swing, timer

How do we run more than one Swing.timer concurrently?

My application is when i hit my jframe button it will execute two swing timer and run concurrently, but it seem this action will make my application run very slow and lagging.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

//************first swing timer execution************************ 

   ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

       jLabel1.setText("Hello Girls");

            }
            };

javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer( 0 , taskPerformer);
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();     // execute first swing timer 


 //************second swing timer execution************************ 

ActionListener taskPerformer1 = new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

       jLabel1.setText("Hello Guys");

            }
            };

javax.swing.Timer timer1 = new javax.swing.Timer( 0 , taskPerformer1);
timer1.setRepeats(true);
timer1.start(); //execute second swing timer
}
```

i notice if i run both timer it will freeze my application. how can i run both timer without freeze or lag?

Comment: `0` millisecond delay would be flooding the EDT with update requests.  Try adding a more reasonable delay

Comment: i have change 0 mili to 5000 mili but it seem my jframe is still freeze. I try to put jtextfield inside my jframe but when i run the application i cant event write anything to the textfield because of the lag.

Comment: There you're doing something else wrong...

Comment: yep, agree. still looking for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A delay of `0` milliseconds is likely flooding the EDT with `Action` events (and other updates event generated by the `setText` call).

You need to provide breathing room for the EDT to not only process your `Action` events, but also the consequences of these events, for example

[image: Timer]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TimerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimerExample();
    }

    public TimerExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private JButton button;

        private Timer hisTimer;
        private Timer herTimer;

        public static final int DELAY = 1000;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            button = new JButton("Start");

            hisTimer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setText("His");
                }
            });
            hisTimer.setInitialDelay(DELAY / 2);
            hisTimer.setCoalesce(true);

            herTimer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setText("Hers");
                }
            });
            herTimer.setCoalesce(true);

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (hisTimer.isRunning() && herTimer.isRunning()) {
                        hisTimer.stop();
                        herTimer.stop();
                        button.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        hisTimer.start();
                        herTimer.start();
                        button.setText("Stop");
                    }
                }
            });

            add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(label);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```